# Calling a powershell script from another powershell script and guaranteeing it is UTF8

Tags: powershell, azure, encoding, utf-8, azure-powershell

I assembled a Powershell script that is designed to grab other scripts that are hosted on Azure blobs, and execute them.

The relevant code blocks:

Obtaining the script:

```
$resp = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $scriptUri -Method GET -ContentType "application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8")
$migrationScript = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($resp.RawContentStream.ToArray());
$tempPath = Get-ScriptDirectory
$fileLocation = CreateTempFile $tempPath "migrationScript.ps1" $migrationScript
```

Creating the file:

```
$newFile = "$tempFolder"+"\"+"$fileName"
Write-Host "Creating temporary file $newFile"
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($newFile, $fileContents)
```

And then I invoke the downloaded file with

```
Invoke-Expression "& `"$fileLocation`" $migrationArgs"
```

This is working well, for what I need. However, the Invoke-Expression is not correctly reading the encoding of the file. It opens correctly in Notepad or Notepad++, but not in ISE (where I am executing the script right now).

Is there a way I can ensure the script is read correctly? It is necessary to support UTF8, as there is a possibility that the scripts will need to perform operations such as setting an AppSetting to a value that contains special characters.

EDIT: Behaviour is the same on "vanilla" non-ISE Powershell invocation.

Comment: Do the scripts have a Unicode BOM for UTF-8 at the beginning of the file?

Comment: 1) `Invoke-Expression` have noting to do with file reading, it only invoke string as PowerShell code. 2) File must contains BOM, for UTF-8 to be recognized by PowerShell. 3) String can be invoked as PowerShell code without saving it to temporary file.

Comment: No, they display without BOM even with Show All Characters in notepad++

Comment: @PetSerAl, I will look into invoking the string as code, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @lit and @PetSerAI, the BOM *is* required for Powershell to work correctly.

My first attempt had not been successful, so I switched back to non-BOM, but, with the following steps, it worked:

1. Perform the Invoke-WebRequest with `-ContentType "application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8"`
2. Grab the Raw content (you will see it in Powershell as a series of numbers, which I assume are the ascii codes?) and convert its bytes with `[system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($resp.RawContentStream.ToArray());` to an array containing the characters you want.
3. When saving the file via .NET's WriteAllText, ensure you use UTF8, 
   `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($newFile, $fileContents, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)`. In this case, UTF8 is understood to be UTF8 *with* a byte order mark, and is what Powershell needs.

Comment: for step 3 you should use `Set-Content -Encoding UTF8`, this will work more universally in PowerShell